# What is the css-selector path to select the value of td element in HTML?

Tags: html, css, xpath, css-selectors

I have a simple table that is burred inside of big HTML file. I do know it has two `td` elements, the first of which is a header label, like `Name` and the second is the value. So what I need to do is to get the text of the second `td`. The problem is HTML is dynamic and the CSS path varies so it inefficient to create a set of CSS paths for each possible case.

It seems like I need to find a `tr` element that has a `td` child that has text 'Name`and then take the text of the last child of that`tr` element. Something in this direction.

```
<html>
...
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>John</td>
          <tr>
        </table>
...   
</html>
```

Comment: You have not provided a concrete description of a real case where you generate HTML markup but cannot generate e.g. `class` attributes for elements to be styled in a particular way. Besides, the title (which refers to the “value” of an element) conflicts with the body (which refers to the content of *another* element, of a sibling). You have accepted an answer that does not seem to address the question asked at all, so it remains a complete mystery what the real question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the CSS dudes  decided not to implement a parent selector. 
It'd make a really foot gun.

Perhaps you can use some javascript search for and add an 'id' to the table you want to restyle.

Comment: The question is not about parent selector but about selecting an element on the basis of the content of its sibling. Impossible too, but a different case, and not addressable using workarounds that may apply to parent selector issue.

Comment: he wants  [has specific content] [parent] smells like a "parent selector" to me.

Comment: The word “parent” does not appear in the question, and neither does the concept. Adding an `id` is hardly a good solution anyway.

Comment: I found a Java workaround for it -- jsoup. It allows finding elements by text. Once I got an element jsoup element has parent property... So yes, logically I don't need parent but I did use one to get to the last of its children (out of 2).